# How to permanently fix small boot partitions

Tags: boot, apt, mount, boot-partition

some Ubuntu versions on some machines setup way to small boot partitions (100M-200M). These get filled by new kernel updates and can lead to failing updates. I encountered this problem on default desktop installs and also some server images.

What would be a good permanent solution for this problem?

Comment: Not using a separate /boot is a good solution.

Comment: Sure, but if you have already used the default image from your provider or the default install routine, configured your system and encountered this problem some months into the system lifetime, how can you fix it without setting up a new system?

Comment: You can always move the `/boot` folder to the `/`. Or, simply use the cleaning command `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` from time to time. If you are using one of the default supported Ubuntu versions, it should remove all but 2 old kernels.

Comment: Yes apt-get autoremove is what I'm  often doing right now on these servers but It's not very convenient. At the same time it's not feasible for people who have no clue of the command line (like relatives that are using ubuntu on a destop). As i wrote I'm looking for a good permanent solution not a workaround. How do you move /boot to /? Please explain in an answer. I suspect it's not totally trivial, because you have to change the grub  configuration.

Comment: Also what happens to kernel updates if you move the boot folder? How does apt know where to put new kernels?

Comment: It is not trivial, but it is not hard. Do you have UEFI or MBR?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40162/discussion-between-samy-ateia-and-dadexix86).